# Changing section heading style

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I would like to change the section/subsection style of my LaTeX document. The following is an example of what I would like:

**3. Methodology and data: An explanation** (Level 1. 12 font. In **bold**. Period after number.)

*3.1. Empirical methods* (Level 2. Subheading in *italics* NOT **bold**. Font size same as level 1. Periods after numbers.)

*3.1.1. Testing vectors* (Level 3. Subsubheading in *italics* NOT **bold**. Font size same as level 1. Periods after numbers.)

Similarly, the above section/subsection style should continue on for all subheadings.

I would like only the above changes to be applied to my entire document. I want all other section/subsection settings to remain as default (i.e, flushed left etc). Cross referencing should also remain as the default, e.g., *3.1.1.* should be cross referenced as "3.1.1" (no italics and no period after the last number).

My MWE is currently:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{2}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}




\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is not minimal. And as a side-remark: Don't use `\linespread[2]`. There are several reasons not to do it. You alredy did load the `setspace` package in your example preamble. Just call `\onehalfspacing` instead.

Comment: @Ruben, Thanks for that. Just wondering, does `\onehalfspacing` produce the same results as `\linespread[2]`? What is its advantage?

Comment: You load booktabs twice!

Comment: @TrueTears: `\linespread` does also affect footnotes and list environments. In most of the cases this is not desirable and `setspace` takes care of these things. (See also [l2tabu](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf), p. 5) And your scepticism is totally appropriate :-) Probabilly the `\doublespaing` macro is the analogue procedure. But I'm not completely certain about it. I would have to look this up too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`titlesec` is able to do what you need:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test Test}
\subsubsection{Test Test Test}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** As your document will be in 12pt, I used `\normalsize` to get the sectioning headings to 12pt.